# Django DRF: How to put two different fields together as one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Have searched many answers but could not find what I am looking for:

I have two fields (one is foreign key) that would return something from the serializer that looks like this:

```
[{"prodID":"SV1", "Amount":"10"},
 {"prodID":"RV1", "Amount":"37"},
 {"prodID":"GG2", "Amount":"22"}]
```

What I would really want, (then I don't have to change my front-end) is:

```
[{"SV1":"10"},
 {"RV1":"37"},
 {"GG2":"22"}]
```

Would this be possible to do with django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override serializer's `to_representation`:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Some

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(SomeSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        new_result = {result['prodID']: result['Amount']}
        return new_result
```

Comment: Do I just include `new_result` in the fields like: `fields = ('new_result')`?

Comment: @AlfaBravo no, You just overriding serializer output. So you dont have do add something to the fields list.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know `to_representation` was what I was looking for, I am reading the docs and see what you mean. Regards.